# Copying a variable javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reference

OK, I'm sure this is a super simple question but other answers I found were a bit too complex for me to understand. I want to create a series of buttons, each sending an alert of the loop iteration it was created in. However, every button sends an alert of "5", the value of i after the loop is finished. How do I make a copy of i instead of accessing the actual value? Is this passing by value or reference?

```
<span id="buttons"></span>
<script>    
  var buttons = document.getElementById("buttons");
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.onclick = function(){alert(i);}
    btn.innerHTML = "Button " + i;
    buttons.appendChild(btn);
  }
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krishnasunder/jeqny4fs/)

Comment: It doesn't make much sense because "id" values must be **unique**. That's why it's called an "id" — it gives the **identity** of the element. Use a class name and then use `.getElementsByClassName()` or `.querySelectorAll()` to access the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have a closure around the `i` variable that is declared outside of the function that you are using it inside of.

Closures can be difficult to understand and you can learn more about them **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)**.

Change the variable declaration to use `let` instead of `var` so that each loop iteration will get its own `i` scoped to it.

```js
// let causes the variable to have block level scope and with a loop
// that means that a separately scoped variable is created for each
// loop iteration. This allows each iteration to have its own unique
// value for the variable that doesn't share a higher level scope.
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.onclick = function(){alert(i);}
        btn.innerHTML = "Button " + i;
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

Comment: It is important to point out the browser support of [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) - while some older browsers (e.g. IE 10-, certain versions of Safari, etc.) are not supported by many websites/web apps, some customers may need to support those browsers; Also see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=let) for more information

Answer (score 2):

One option is to wrap the event handler in a [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (immediately invoked function expression).

In doing so, you are capturing and passing the value of `i` on each iteration.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/7o7kewzv/)

```
(function (i) {
  btn.onclick = function() {
    alert(i);
  }
})(i);
```

---

Another option would be to use the [`bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to pass the value of `i` on each iteration:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/tc5zbgmf/)

```
btn.onclick = function(index) {
  alert(index);
}.bind(null, i);
```

---

However, a better option may be to set a `data-*` attribute on the elements on each iteration, and then in the event listener you can access that element's data attribute:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/16yr0f07/)

```
btn.dataset.index = i;
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert(this.dataset.index);
});
```